# How to reduce for-loops in this code?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, probability, performance

I am doing calculations that involves too many for-loops. I would appreciate any idea that could eliminates some of the loops to make the algorithm more efficient. Here is the mathematical expression I want to get: A discrete distribution of random variable Y.

Pr(Y=y )=
∑_Pr(Z=z) ∙∑_Pr((X=x) ∑_Pr(W=w) ∙∑_Pr(R=r│W=w) ∙Pr(S=z+y-x-r|W=w)
Y,Z,X,W,R,S are discrete random variable, they are dependent. I know the expression for each term, but there are just probability calculations – not close-form distributions.

```
    array Y[max_Y+1]；  % store the distribution of Y
temp1=0, temp2=0, temp3=0, temp4=0; % summation for partial distributions
for y = 0 max_Y
    temp1=0;
    for z = 0 : 5- y
        temp2=0;
        for x=0:5
            temp3=0;
            for w=0:5
                temp4=0
                for r=0:w
                    temp4=temp4+Pr(R=r│W=w)∙Pr(S=z+y-x-r|W=w);
                    end
                temp3=temp3+temp4*Pr(W=w);
                end
            temp2= temp2+temp3*Pr(X=x);
            end
       temp1=temp1+temp2* P(Z=z);
       end
   Y[y]=temp1;
   end
```

Thanks a lot!
Ester

Comment: I cant understand the way it is written. Modify it or dump it.

Answer (score 0):

From what I notice in every iteration only the term `Pr(S=z+y-x-r|W=w) & Pr(Z=z)` is dependent on your function input variable Y so all other value can be precomputed using separate for-loops and then just compute `Pr(S=z+y-x-r|W=w)*Pr(Z=z)*precomputed`